# US Visa on Old Passport with Cancelled Stamp

Tags: usa, passports, b1-b2-visas, passport-renewals

I have a US B1/B2 visa on my old passport. The old passport has a cancelled stamp on the second page. The visa is still intact with no physical damage. My new passport is of the same type and has the same name as in my old passport. I have read on travel.state.gov that it should be fine. I am a bit concerned about the 'cancelled' stamp on the old passport. The bio page on the old passport is completely legible and of course the visa is perfectly intact without any damage.
Can someone tell me if I will have any issues travelling to the states?

Comment: The cancelled stamp is your government stating your old passport is no longer valid. This has no application the US Visa which is issued by the USA and can only be cancelled by the USA. Bring both passports and you'll be fine!

Comment: Thanks! It worked out and I was able to travel without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the OP's comment yesterday, it worked out and had no issue.  Bringing both passports to present at the border provides the requirement of evidence.

[image]